# Как удалить все сообщения в беседе telegram, кроме закрепленного pyrogram

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

Я пишу юзербота и мне необходим функционал очистки сообщений. Только в группе есть закрепленное сообщение, которое удалять не нужно. Я искал в интернете, но не смог сообразить, как спарсить сообщения и всех их удалить, кроме самого верхнего.

```
async def handleCommands(client: Client, message: Message):
    if message.chat.id == manage_channel_id and message.text == '/clear':
        for mesID in range(message.id - 50, message.id + 1):
            print(mesID)
            await client.delete_messages(manage_channel_id, mesID)
```

Сейчас у меня все работает кастыльно, то есть удаляется текущее сообщение '/clear' и 50 за ним(по id). Как удалить только те сообщения, что есть в беседе за исключением одного закрепленного?